# CefSharp RegisterJsObject method throwing exception object already bound

Tags: c#, wpf, chromium, cefsharp

I am working on WPF application and I am using **CefSharp** **ChromiumWebBrowser**.

I am using below code to register browser object into ChromiumBrowser-

```
browser.RegisterJsObject("bound1", new BoundObject());
```

But when I am opening multiple windows simultaneously I am getting below error:

***{System.ArgumentException: Object already bound with name:bound1
Parameter name: bound1
   at CefSharp.Internals.JavascriptObjectRepository.Register(String name, Object value, Boolean isAsync, BindingOptions options)}***

I tried below things to fix this-

```
browser.LegacyJavascriptBindingEnabled = true
browser.RegisterJsObject("bound1", new BoundObject());
```

But still I am getting the same error. Any suggestion to fix this would appreciated.

Comment: Is something unclear about the error?

Comment: @amaitland, It seems the object is already contains with same name in browser but I am not getting the way to handle it. Means if the object is there then it should not call the "RegisterJsObject" function.

Comment: http://cefsharp.github.io/api/63.0.0/html/M_CefSharp_IJavascriptObjectRepository_IsBound.htm

Comment: http://cefsharp.github.io/api/63.0.0/html/P_CefSharp_IWebBrowser_JavascriptObjectRepository.htm